# proguard to enable sherlockfragments in real devise steps

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, proguard, android-2.2-froyo

I realy need help,  my android app. uses sherlockActivity that holds 3 sherlockListFragments, my min sdk req. is 2.2 , when i ran it on emulator it runs perfectly, but on the real device (run on 2.2) it gives a force close.
After hours of search, i edited my proguard-project.txt and project.properties and i updated my android developer toolkit level to 20.1, and i downloaded proguard 4.9 and put the jars in my sdk/tools/lib direc. 
then i made export to the .apk file, But It gave me the same results :(((
This is the proguard-project.txt

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontwarn android.support.**
-verbose

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify


-keepattributes *Annotation* 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keep class android.support.v4.app.**{*;}
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.**{*;}

-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.**{*;}
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.**{*;}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

 -keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
 }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}
```

In my project.properties file i removed the comment of proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

Please i need help in details , because i'm new to android
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you create an APK without proguard does it run ok? What is the stacktrace when it does crash?

Comment: without proguard, the same result, it runs ok in emulator and it give me force close on real phone.

Comment: @Blundell , you saw this comment ?

Comment: @Fareed did you try the exported apk on emulator. using `adb install myApp.apk` or just the debug apk file? Either way, try getting the Logcat and check what caused the force close.

Comment: If it force closes on a real phone without ProGuard, then proguard isn't your problem!